# How to compare the string and ignore the starting string from a sentence in JAVAScript

Tags: javascript, html, comparison

I want to check the text and know if the text content is exceeding more than 70 characters
and show which ever line has exceeding characters.
Code:

```
if((str.charAt(i) != '\n') && (i!=(len-1)))
    {
        TChars = TChars + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if(TChars >= 71)
        {
            Tres =  Tres + Lno + ", ";
        }
        TChars = 0;
        Lno = Lno + 1;

    } if(Tres.length < 1)

Tres = "No ";

document.AsciiConvert.HTMLResults.value += Tres + "line number have more than 70 characters.\n";
```

So my Question is if i can ignore the links in the text content which starts from 'http' and give the result for the texts exceeding 70 characters only not about the URLs length
Answers will be very much appreciated.

Thank you,
Sagar

Answer (score 0):

you can use;

String text= links.substring("http"+1, links.length());

text is a string without "http", for example:

links = "http://stackoverflow.com"

after you use my line code, you obtain

text= "://stackoverflow.com".

So, you should add this where you have the complete string

Comment: So you mean that http will be removed from the text content,

Comment: but i want the entire link starting http should be ignored and i want the length of the characters shown for text.

Comment: i don´t understand you well, want to know the number of characters of text? in this case; int long =text.length()

Comment: Okay let me explain you what my above code does is it scans each line and if any line consists of more than 70 characters it displays which line has it. So what my question is i want to ignore the urls in the text content so that it wont display url's line number as i would want to ignore the url irrespective of its length.